# Unable to compile Lex and Yacc programs

Tags: gcc, yacc, lex

I am trying to compile few lex and yacc programs. In college we use Fedora Core 4. I use the same OS on a virtual machine at home but I am unable compile the program. The following are the lex and yacc codes

LEX Code

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[ \t]+ {;}
\n {return;}
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {return ID;}
[0-9]+ {return NUMBER;}
. {return yytext[0];} 
%%
```

YACC Code

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
%}
%token NUMBER ID
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%
input:e'+'e
|e'-'e
|e'*'e
|e'/'e
|'('e')'
;
e:NUMBER
|ID
;
%%
int main()
{
printf("\n\nEnter an expression");
yyparse();
printf("\n\nValid Expression\n\n");
}
void yyerror()
{
printf("\n\nInvalid Expression\n\n");
exit(0);
}

While executing the above code, I get the following linker error

$ lex program_name.l                      //executes without error
$ yacc -d program_name.y                  //executes without error
$ cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll -ly
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me solve this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[This conversion](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/gcc-ly-not-working-675032/) outlines your problem: you need liby to be installed and the compiler needs to have the right library path set (e.g. -L/usr/lib)

The `-ly` option tells the linker to link with the liby library, but according to the error, it cannot find that library

Answer (score 1):

this has to do with your yacc lib...
you will need to include the directory with the `-L"/some/path/to/lib-directory"` option

or possibly you need to install the appropriate lib...

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `-ly`. Lex and flex generated scanners use a run-time support library. A yacc generated parser does not. Just take out the `-ly` and try again.